# attach a filestring in cakephp cakeemail through error

Tags: php, cakephp

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->layout='pdf';
$view = new View(null, false);

$view->viewPath = 'Policies';  //folder to look in in Views directory
$output = $view->render('lodge_claim', 'pdf'); 

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail('default');
$Email->config('default');
$Email->from(array('pankaj.jarial@netsolutionsindia.com' => 'My Site'));
$Email->to('pankaj.jarial@netsolutionsindia.com');
$Email->subject('About');
$Email->attachments(array('invoice.pdf'=>array('data'=>$output)));
$Email->send('My message');
```

This is code of my controller function I dont know what is the error. It is showing file not specified error

Comment: You don't get an error, but there is an error? What's the output you receive?

Comment: It is showing file not specified. I know we should pass file in $Email->attachments but I have to send dataString so I have passed data as attachment.

Comment: I sort it out. My code was correct there was error in cakephp CakeEmail class I replaced it with file that I get from following link https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php